# How to downcast array of object type into an normal array?

Tags: java, types, downcast, mismatch

I planned to convert an `ArrayList` into an normal array. After that i tried to downcast that object type into a normal array.But its showing that "Cannot convert from Object to int" at line 17.

```
package coll;

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ToArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList a1=new ArrayList();
        a1.add(new Integer(2));
        a1.add(new Integer(8));
        a1.add(new Integer(7));
        a1.add(new Integer(6));
     System.out.println("the contents are"+ a1);
     Object ia[]=a1.toArray();
     int[] a=new int[5];
     for(Object i:ia)
     {
        a[i]=((Integer)ia[i]).intValue(); 
     }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array takes only int value for indexing. In for loop you are trying to put object value for indexing so Downcast exception is coming.

Instead of :

```
for(Object i:ia){
     a[i]=((Integer)ia[i]).intValue(); 
}
```

Use below code :

```
for(int i=0;i<ia.length;i++){
    a[i] = ((Integer) ia[i]).intValue();
}
```

Comment: ya.. Thanks.. I'm just a beginner. I'm having a doubt. For each can be used for iterating array values.. here i'm using 'foreach' to iterating an array containing object type. cant we use for each??

Comment: You can use foreach loop to iterate arraylist containing object but you are trying to assign value to array also same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
        a1.add(new Integer(2));
        a1.add(new Integer(8));
        a1.add(new Integer(7));
        a1.add(new Integer(6));
        System.out.println("the contents are" + a1);

        Integer[] ia = (Integer[])a1.toArray(new Integer[a1.size()]);

        for (int i : ia) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all use Generics and always use Super Type to Reference An Object**

Like This `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Secondly there is no need to do this

```
list.add(new Integer(5));
```

You can directly do this `list.add(5);` the **automatic Wrapping and Unwrapping will be done.**

And about the Array thing do this,

```
int arr[] = new int[list.size()];

Iterator<Integer> i  =list.iterator();
int count =0 ;
while(i.hasNext())
{
   arr[count] = i.next();
   count++;
}
```

**By Using Generics your ArrayList understands that it should accept Integers only. And you don't need to Downcast or Upcast Anything** :D

Comment: Please Refer to documentation. You get to learn a lot by reading documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Thanks alot. As a beginner now only i came to know about the importance of generics.great job..